# Navigate to uri with umlaut using wpf webbrowser control

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I'm using a WPF `WebBrowser` control to navigate to an URI containing a PDF file like that:

**XAML**

```
<WebBrowser x:Name="Browser" Loaded="Browser_OnLoaded"/>
```

**Code behind**

```
        url = @"file:///c:\A.pdf"; // This works
        url = @"file:///c:\Ä.pdf"; // This shows error

        Browser.Navigate(url);
```

**Error with Ä.pdf**

[image]

**Question**

How can I navigate to the file with umlaut?

I tried UrlEncoding, changing to ASCII encoding, using extended ASCII all without success. Is it possible?

---

**Edit**

Using `WebUtility.UrlEncode("Ä");` produces `%C3%84` Why?:

[image]

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the other question talks about a file containing Umlauts. My question is about an Uri with umlauts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it work with WebBrowser, you must update the encoding. By referencing the System.Web assembly you can use:

```
  System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Ä", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));
```

---

For below examples, I have used the character `Ä`.

All, non ASCII characters must be encoded in the URL using percent-encoded characters. It is explained in the following RFC (page 21, last paragraph of section 3.2.2): [https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.3).

*Non-ASCII characters must first be encoded according to UTF-8 [STD63], and then each octet of the corresponding UTF-8 sequence must be percent-encoded to be represented as URI characters.*

So the UTF8 character corresponding to `Ä` is `C3 84`. Which corresponds to the percent-encoded value: `%C3%84`.

You can use the following code to encode your file name:

```
System.Net.WebUtility.UrlEncode("Ä");
```

or

```
Uri.EscapeUriString("Ä");
```

Comment: Is there a convenient method to do this in .NET? I tried UrlEncode without success...

Comment: UrlEncode("Ä") produces "%C3%84". Why? I think there might be a problem UTF8 vs ASCII....

Comment: Yes, you have right. That's the UTF8 character in its percent-encoded form. In my first answer I made a mistake with *Numerical character reference* that can be used in HTML or XML (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numeric_character_reference). I have updated my answer with the percent-encoded characters explanation.

Comment: But it won't work with the WebBrowser control if I use "%C3%84" in the Url. It only works if I use "%C3" alone. Can you provide a code example of the encoding I have to do to achieve that result?

Comment: So you have to update the encoding. By referencing the System.Web assembly you can use: `System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Ä", Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")));`

Comment: With your last comment, it works for äöü. Thanks for your help. I still had problems with spaces in the url of the filename. But I just replaced them with another char.

Comment: Can you move your last comment to the answer? I think the solution is clearer then...

Comment: I have updated the answer. Space characters should be replaced by %20.

Answer (score 4):

I think the solution here is not to try fancy encoding, but use the `Uri` class.

This works for me in the WPF WebBrowser control:

```
var uri = new Uri("c:\users\täto\AppData\Roaming\MarkdownMonster\_preview.html");
PreviewBrowser.Navigate(uri);
```

It appears the Uri class handles all the encoding with no fuss.

Comment: This solved my issue with Danish letters ÆØÅ in file paths.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried: `@"file:///c:\Certific%E4te.pdf"` instead of `@"file:///c:\Certificäte.pdf"` (as an example)?

More umlauts:

- Ä = %C4
- Ö = %D6
- Ü = %DC
- ä = %E4
- ö = %F6
- ü = %FC
- ß = %DF
- € = %u20AC
- $ = %24
- % = %25